# Draw Border from Region

Tags: vb.net, gdi+

I'm trying to draw a border around the region of my Button, but I cannot figure out how to convert the Region property to usable GDI+ data.

Currently I'm setting the region equal to the result from the CreateRoundRectRgn API:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class RoundButton
    Inherits Button

    Private _radius As Integer = 10
    Public Property Radius As Integer
        Get
            Return _radius
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            If value < 0 OrElse value > 90 Then
                Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("The radius cannot be less than 0 or greater than 90.")
            End If
            If _radius <> value Then
                _radius = value
                Me.OnRadiusChanged()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overridable Sub OnRadiusChanged()
        RaiseEvent RadiusChanged(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
    End Sub

    Public Event RadiusChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPaint(e)

        Dim border_size As Integer = If(MyBase.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat, MyBase.FlatAppearance.BorderSize, 1)

        'Set the region
        MyBase.Region = Region.FromHrgn(CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, MyBase.Width - border_size, MyBase.Height - border_size, _radius, _radius))

        'Fill the color
        Using background As Brush = New SolidBrush(MyBase.BackColor)
            e.Graphics.FillRegion(background, MyBase.Region)
        End Using
    End Sub

    <DllImport("Gdi32.dll", EntryPoint:="CreateRoundRectRgn")>
    Private Shared Function CreateRoundRectRgn(ByVal nLeftRect As Integer, ByVal nTopRect As Integer, ByVal nRightRect As Integer, ByVal nBottomRect As Integer, ByVal nWidthEllipse As Integer, ByVal nHeightEllipse As Integer) As IntPtr
    End Function

End Class
```

This works great *IF* I don't want to add a border, but since I want to add a  border, I need to figure how to convert the data from the control's Region to usable GDI+ data. What I've attempted to do is get the rectangles from the GetRegionScans property of the region like this:

```
'Draw the border
Using border As Pen = New Pen(border_color, border_size)
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangles(border, MyBase.Region.GetRegionScans(New Drawing2D.Matrix()))
End Using
```

But this draws a bunch of rectangles inside of my Button, rather than outlining the border.

Comment: There is really no need to use CreateRoundRectRgn.  You can create a Region from a GraphicsPath.  Also creating the Region in the OnPaint method is ill-advised, consider doing so in SetBoundsCore.  Also, Region is Disposable, so cleanup the existing one before creating a new one.  Consider using  a GraphicPath to draw the border.  Look at the GraphicsPath.Widen example in the documentation.

Comment: @TnTinMn - The reason why I'm using CreateRoundRectRgn is to avoid drawing the rounded edges manually.

Comment: The issue is that Regions are basically for defining a viewable area.  GraphicsPaths can be used to define a Region, but AFAIK the reverse is not possible.  Once you have a GraphicsPath defined, you can easily accomplish your goal.